# Gauge Invariance of Schrodinger Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, schroedinger-equation, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

I was working out the math of Gauge Invariance of Schrodinger Equation.
Gauge transformations on my $\psi$, and the fields $\vec{A}$, and $A_0$ are
\begin{eqnarray*}
\psi(x)&\rightarrow& e^{i\alpha(x)}  \psi(x)\\
 \vec A &\rightarrow& \vec A + \frac{1}{q} \vec\nabla \alpha(x,t)\\
 A_0 &\rightarrow& A_0 - \frac{1}{q} \partial_0 \alpha(x,t)
\end{eqnarray*}

> I need to show that 
>   \begin{eqnarray*}
> i \frac{\partial \psi'}{\partial t}&=& H' \psi'\\
> \implies i \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}&=& H \psi
> \end{eqnarray*}
>   where my Hamiltonian is given by
>   \begin{eqnarray*}
> H=\frac{1}{2m}(p-qA)^2 + qA_0
> \end{eqnarray*}

First I try the kinetic energy term, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(p-qA')^2 \psi' &=& \left(-i \vec\nabla -qA-\vec\nabla\alpha\right)^2 (e^{i\alpha} \psi)\\
&=&\left(i \vec\nabla +qA+\vec\nabla\alpha\right)\left(i \vec\nabla +qA+\vec\nabla\alpha\right) (e^{i\alpha} \psi)\\
&=& \left(i \vec\nabla +qA+\vec\nabla\alpha\right)
\left[ ie^{i\alpha}\vec\nabla\psi
+qAe^{i\alpha}\psi
\right]\\
&=&   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
- \vec\nabla
\left( e^{i\alpha}\vec\nabla\psi\right)
+i \vec\nabla\left(qAe^{i\alpha}\psi
\right)
+\left(qA+\vec\nabla\alpha\right) \left[ ie^{i\alpha}\vec\nabla\psi +qAe^{i\alpha}\psi \right]\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, I am worried about the second term in the last line above,
$i \vec\nabla\left(qAe^{i\alpha}\psi\right)$. I assume that should be 
\begin{eqnarray*}
i \vec\nabla\left(qAe^{i\alpha}\psi\right) =
iq\left(\vec\nabla A\right)e^{i\alpha}\psi
+iqA\left(\vec\nabla e^{i\alpha}\right)\psi
+iqAe^{i\alpha}\left(\vec\nabla\psi\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
My problem isn't solved unless $\vec \nabla A$ is zero. Now, is it zero?
What is it anyway? Divergence of $\vec A$ or gradient of $\vec A$?
If it's divergence, then that is zero only in electrostatics. If it is a gradient, then it has some other [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Generalizations)  [component](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156880/152241).

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94699/46907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is also solved if $\vec\nabla A$ is non-zero. Your last line equals
$$ \mathrm e^{\mathrm i\alpha} \left( -\Delta \psi + \mathrm i q\, (\vec\nabla \cdot \vec A)\, \psi + 2 \mathrm i q\, \vec A \cdot \vec\nabla \psi + (q\vec A)^2\, \psi\right) \;. $$

Note that this is the same as
$$ \mathrm e^{\mathrm i\alpha}\, ( \vec p - q\vec A ) ( \vec p - q\vec A )\, \psi \;. $$

**Edit** to respond to comment.

You already did everything correctly in your question, $\vec p - q\vec A$ acts as follows on a wave function $\psi(x)$:
$$ (( \vec p - q\vec A ) \psi)(x) = -\mathrm i\hbar\, \vec \nabla \psi(x) - q\vec A(x)\, \psi(x) $$
If you act again from the left with $\vec p - q\vec A$, you just take the inner product.
Thinking about this in terms of gradients, divergences etc is possible but not too helpful, it's better to just think in components:
$$ (( \vec p - q\vec A )^2 \psi)(x) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \bigl( -\mathrm i\hbar\, \partial_i - q A_i(x) \bigr) \bigl( -\mathrm i\hbar\, \partial_i \psi(x) - q A_i(x)\, \psi(x) \bigr) $$

Comment: thanks, understood. But the primary doubt is only clear, and not the second. can you please also state as to how we should treat this exactly? a gradient or a divergence? since $\vec p - q\vec A$ is itself a vector operator, how should it act on $\vec p - q\vec A$ which has already acted on $e^{i\alpha} \psi$?

Comment: @MycrofD I edited my reply